# Any good spatial database tutorials out there?

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, spatial, postgis

I was looking to explore the spatial capabilities of PostGIS or SQL Server 2008. Maybe Oracle as well.

I was wondering if there are any good tutorials out there exploring the spatial capabilities of these database in particular or of this type of capability in general.

Does anyone know of any? Book recommendations would work as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote a little blogpost about SQL Server geography data type here: [SQL Server 2008 Proximity Search With The Geography Data Type](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/sql-server-2008-proximity-search-with-th)

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a tutorial, bit it's a good comparison of the various offerings, to see how they stack up against one another:
[Spatial Database Cross Compare](http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=sqlserver2008_postgis_mysql_compare)

Answer (score 3):

A great introduction to SQL Server 2008 Spatial in 8 parts. Projections, geography / geometry, spatial SQL functions etc.

http://www.jasonfollas.com/blog/archive/2008/03/14/sql-server-2008-spatial-data-part-1.aspx

A few extra links and SQL examples here - http://geographika.co.uk/sql-server-spatial-sql

Answer (score 3):

Try http://www.bostongis.com/

They mostly cover Postgres/PostGIS, though they talk about SQL Server also. There are some pretty good examples.

The PostGIS manual is really good too, chapters 4 and 6 in particular, though it is all worth reading.

http://www.postgis.org/docs/ch04.html

PostGIS again, but this book is really very comprehensive in its coverage of spatial sql, and many of the queries will port to other dbs, particularly Oracle -- as the Postgres devs have made an effort to be compatable with Oracle syntax, where possible. It starts with the basics, but some of the later examples are really very advanced.

http://www.manning.com/obe/

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in [ESRI's ArcSDE tutorials](http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0799/arcsde.html).

**Edit:** Sorry... I just read the question details.  And this doesn't really answer your specific need.  However, for people looking for an SDE tutorial that are using the ESRI products, they may find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

While it doesn't specifically address SQL Server 2008, Boundless has a very good [tutorial](http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/) on PostGIS.  I didn't use their OpenGeo Suite to follow along but instead adapted the examples to PostgreSQL which is what I use.  In the end, I learned a lot from this tutorial paired with the PostGIS user manual.

Comment: This is a 5 year old question. Not only that, the question is off-topic for SO